# How can I delete a directory like this "-work.lib++" in linux?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to delete a directory which name is "-work.lib++" in linux.
But I am still failing. rm -rf -work.lib++
Would you please lwt me know how to remove the directory?

Comment: `rm -r './-work.lib++'` or `rm -r -- '-work.lib++'`

Comment: Thanks knittl if you can write as answer I can accpet you